# When checkbox ticked, any cells with a value of 0 display a word instead

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of calculations which all cells have formulas. I want a checkbox which when ticked replaces all cells in the table which are 0 with the word "None".

I have seen some suggestions using formulas.

I tried a few ways but can't figure out how to write a checkbox macro in which two variables need to be met to run the macro.

Comment: Please share what you have!

Comment: I doubt you need a macro and the checkbox implies that sometimes your want on "None" and sometimes you want "0" - is that true? Also be aware that having mixed types in a column means you won't be able to use it for any subsequent calculations. 
An alternative is to use Accounting format which will display "-" for 0

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't modify your data unless it is really necessary. In this case, you can achieve your goal by setting the `NumberFormat` of the cells instead.

The number format in Excel contains up to 4 part (that are separated by ";"). The first part is for positive numbers, the second is for negative numbers, the third is for 0 (and the forth for strings, but we can igore that). A possible number format would be `General;General;"None"`: For everything except 0, the `General` format would apply. For `0`, Excel would display `None` (but note that the *value* of the cell doesn't change, only the way it is displayed in the sheet).

Now all you have to do is:
**o** Go to the VBA Editor, add a Module (if you don't have any) and add the following code:

```
Sub ShowHideZeros()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  ' Replace with your sheet name
        Dim showNone As Boolean
        showNone = (.CheckBoxes(1).Value = xlOn)
        Dim r as Range
        ' Use this to format all cells
        Set r = .UsedRange
        ' Use this instead if you want to format only specific cells:
        ' Set r = .Range("A2:A100")
        If showNone Then
            .UsedRange.NumberFormat = "General;General;""None"""
        Else
            .UsedRange.NumberFormat = "General"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**o** Place a checkbox on your sheet and give it a meaningfull text, eg `Show "None" for 0`. Note that there are 2 different types of checkboxes, this example assumes that you use a so called "Form-Control" (that's the upper part of the control selection).

[image]

**o** Right click on the checkbox and choose "Assign Macro". Select the routine `ShowHideZeros`.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable lesson. I wasn't aware of most of it.

Answer (score 2):

"I have a table of calculations which all already have formulas in them". I think this is the key. The formulas are there and have to stay there. So we can set the formating:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()   'ActiveX checkBox
   Call toggleNone
   With CheckBox1
      If .value Then
         .Caption = "Zeros as 0"
      Else
         .Caption = "Zeros as None"
      End If
   End With
End Sub

Sub toggleNone()
   Dim t As ListObject, r As Range, setNone As Boolean
   setNone = Me.CheckBox1.value
   Set t = Me.ListObjects("CALCTABLE")
   For Each r In t.DataBodyRange
      If r.Value2 = 0 Then
         If setNone Then
   'IN NEXT LINE INSTEAD OF ; USE THE LOCAL LIST SEPARATOR (maybe , )
            r.NumberFormat = " ; ; ""None"" ; -"
         Else
            r.NumberFormat = "General"
         End If
      Else
         r.NumberFormat = "General"
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Toggle Matching Values Using a Forms Check Box

[image]

- It is assumed that your data is a table starting in `A1` with one row of headers.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ToggleNone()
    
    Const WorksheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CheckBoxName As String = "Check Box 1"
    Const CellString As String = "None"
    Const CellNumber As Double = 0
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WorksheetName)
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim chkValue As Long: chkValue = ws.CheckBoxes(CheckBoxName).Value
    
    Dim OldValue, NewValue, VarValue As Long
    
    If chkValue = 1 Then ' Checked (1)
        OldValue = CellNumber
        NewValue = CellString
        VarValue = vbDouble
    Else ' Unchecked (-4146)
        OldValue = CellString
        NewValue = CellNumber
        VarValue = vbString
    End If
        
    Dim urg As Range, cell As Range, CurrentValue
    
    ' Combine
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        CurrentValue = cell.Value
        If VarType(CurrentValue) = VarValue Then
            If CurrentValue = OldValue Then
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = cell
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Replace
    If Not urg Is Nothing Then
        Dim arg As Range
        For Each arg In urg.Areas
            arg.Value = NewValue
        Next arg
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that 1 = `xlOn` and -4146 = `xlOff`

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, I knew it [3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878811). Getting old.